# Fetch the spaces and new line characters from textarea using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using an ASP.NET `<asp:TextBox>` with `TextMode="MultiLine"`.

If I fetch the value from `.cs` file I get the spaces and new line characters also (`\r\n`). But if I fetch the value of the same textbox using javscript I am not getting those values.

ASPX Code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSample" Width="130px" Height="65px" runat="server" Rows="10"
   Columns="5" ClientIDMode="Static" TextMode="MultiLine" Wrap="true">
</asp:TextBox>
```

Javascript Code :

```
var valueinTextbox = $('#<%=txtSample.ClientID%>').text();
```

The values in the textbox will be:

```
12345
12458
12775

21544
```

(please note that each number that is entered in the textbox is in new line)

In C# code I am getting `12345\r\n12458\r\n12775\r\n\r\n21544`

In Javascript code I am getting `12345124581277521544`

How can I get the same new line character in javascript?

Comment: What are you checking the javascript value with?  [This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wLb3z/1/) appears to show it working correctly.

Comment: i save the previous value of the textbox in a hidden field from c# code. i need to compare whether some change is made or not to the value in textbox before clicking on save button.